# Como relacionar Modelos de la forma correcta en laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

Verán, estoy trabajando con 3 modelos, el inmueble, el tipo de inmueble y la ubicación del inmueble, pasa que el tipo de inmueble y la ubicación del inmueble son atributos del inmueble (cabe resaltar que son en relación uno a uno, es decir, un inmueble tiene solo un tipo de inmueble y una sola ubicación), el problema es que no se como relacionarlas de la forma correcta en laravel, por ejemplo al crear un inmueble, quiero que en su formulario haya un select que muestre las opciones existentes en la tabla (base de datos) de tipos de inmueble, es decir que si en la table de la base de datos tengo:

1. Opción uno
2. Opción dos
3. Opción tres

En el select deberían salir estas mismas opciones disponibles

También quisiera que alguien me explicara mas a fondo el uso de los métodos que retornan cosas como:

`return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key');`

Estos son los métodos de definición de relación, como Uno a muchos, muchos a muchos o uno a uno (adjunto la documentación de laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

No entendí muy bien la documentación de laravel y no entendí como se deben usar dichos métodos, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al tener una relación 1-1 es necesario el uso de método *[hasOne](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)* a la hora de acceder a las relaciones, por ejemplo teniendo el Modelo Inmueble tendrías dos funciones alli las cuales hacen referencia a que tiene relación con los otros dos modelos.

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Inmobiliaria extends Model
{
/*
 * Relación con la ubicación.
 */
 public function Ubicacion()
 {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Ubicacion','ubicacion_id');
 }
/*
Acá especificas que tiene relación con las opcion especifica
*/
 public function Opcion()
 {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Opciones','opcion_id');
 }
}
```

Con esto en el modelo el laravel podrá saber que al acceder a la instancia de ese objeto traerá la relación:

```
$inmobiliaria = Inmobiliaria::find(1);
$Ubicacion    = $inmobiliaria->Ubicacion;
$Opcion       = $inmobiliaria->Opcion;
```

Tambien puedes usar el [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) que consiste en hacer una carga y evitar el error n+1, quedaria algo así

```
$inmobiliaria = Inmobiliaria::with('Ubicacion', 'Opcion')->get();
/*Haciendo esto ya nuestras relaciones vienen cargadas y evitamos hacer una consulta con cada petición o acceso a la relación*/
foreach ($inmobiliaria as $valor) {
 echo $valor->Ubicacion; /*para acceder al nombre solo debes colocar acceso a la propiedad $valor->Ubicacion->name*/
 echo $valor->Opcion;
}
```

Comment: Entiendo y te agradezco mucho, ya entiendo como es el acceso a dichos atributos, pero tengo la otra duda que mencione antes, ¿Como seria la forma correcta de llamar a esos datos de la opción y la ubicación en la vista de registro del inmueble?

Comment: A la hora de registro al ser 1 a 1 , puedes guardar el id de la option y el id de la ubicación, en la vista crear puedes hacer la consulta y pasarle los datos al select de option y al de ubicación

Comment: Mi duda des como le deberia pasar los datos al select, en este momento estoy usando los modelos de ubicacion y option en el controller de Inmueble, en el metodo create retorno los datos que se guardan en esta variable $ubicaciones = Ubicacion::all();

Pero no estoy seguro de si deba hacerse asi

Comment: No se si exista otra manera, pero si , así normalmente se hace y en la vista seleccionas los campos que requieras.

Comment: Entiendo, soy algo nuevo en laravel y no estaba seguro de si se debia realizar asi, aclaraste mi duda, muchisimas gracias

Comment: De nada amigo, bienvenido a este mundo tan hermoso de Laravel.